# Default WSO2 ESB server login credentials?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I just setup WSO2 ESB and got it started in the command line console.  I have the Management Console webpage running in a browser now but am stuck on the login.  Is there a default username/password to use as a start here?

Any help is appreciated.

Rick Price

Comment: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Introducing+the+Management+Console

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, **admin** username and **admin** password should get you through that login page and into the WSO2 ESB's dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For the super tenant,

Username : **admin**

Password : **admin**

If it some other tenant, (e.g.: if tenant name is **abc.com**, admin username is **admin** and password is **password123**)

Username : **admin@abc.com**

Password : **password123**